# How would you include the current commit id in a Git project's files?

Tags: git

I've got an open source static JavaScript + HTML application that's deployed in about three different places right now, one on my local machine, one on an internal server, and one on a stable external server.

I'd like to be able to tell immediately which version is deployed in which place, and I'd like bug reporters to have easy access to the version that they're reporting the bug on.

Ideally I'd like, as part of the commit process, for a file to be written with the hash of the commit. Of course, from what I know of Git this is impossible, as including the calculated hash as part of a file in a commit would change the calculated hash of that commit.

On the other hand, I could incorporate building this as part of a build process. I don't currently have a build process though, and I'd like to avoid adding a step if possible.

What's the cleanest way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add it to your automated deploy system.

If your deploy isn't automated, then automate it and add it there.  Then you have removed a step.

Make it a more useful "this was deployed on x date at y time from z repository".  The hash of the commit doesn't really mean a whole lot to non-developers.

Comment: I'd add "git describe" output.

Answer (score 30):

There are some subtleties to this because of the nature of Git.  The way I've done this is by copying what the Git developers themselves do.  First, you'll want to use annotated tags which is probably a good idea anyway.  To review, you can create a new tag like this:

```
$ git tag -a -m "Version 0.2" v0.2 HEAD
```

Then (as suggested in Otto's post) you can use `git describe` for a useful "version" string that will include the number of commits since the tag and the leading digits of the sha1 of the the current commit.  Here's an example from one of my projects:

```
$ git describe
v1.0-3-gee47184
```

That is, this copy is 3 commits ahead of the "v1.0" tag and the commit sha1 begins with ee47184 (I'm not sure why they include that leading 'g').

The Git developers take it one step further and also include an extra bit if the working copy is modified (uncommitted).  This requires a few more steps so it's all wrapped up in a script they name `VERSION-GEN`.  When run, it prints the version string to standard output and also creates a `VERSION-FILE` file (the script is careful to not re-touch that file if the version hasn't changed -- so it's build-tool friendly).  Then, you can include that `VERSION-FILE` file in your source code, help files, etc.

Using my example `VERSION-GEN` script (below), my version string for the above example is:

```
$ VERSION-GEN
version: 1.0-3-gee47
```

If I modify any of the tracked files it looks like this:

```
$ VERSION-GEN
version: 1.0-3-gee47-mod
```

Here's my slightly tweaked version of `VERSION-GEN`.  Note that it expects that the tags marking versions are of the form v[0-9]* (e.g., v1.0 or v0.2 or v12.3.4 or v12.2-4feb2009 etc.)

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

# Tag revisions like this:
# $ git tag -a -m "Version 0.2" v0.2 HEAD

VF=VERSION-FILE
DEFAULT_VERSION=UKNOWN

LF='
'

# First see if there is a version file (included in release tarballs),
# then try git-describe, then default.
if test -d .git -o -f .git &&
    VN=$(git describe --abbrev=4 HEAD 2>/dev/null) &&
    case "$VN" in
    *$LF*) (exit 1) ;;
    v[0-9]*)
        git update-index -q --refresh
        test -z "$(git diff-index --name-only HEAD --)" ||
        VN="$VN-mod" ;;
    esac
then
        continue
    #VN=$(echo "$VN" | sed -e 's/-/./g');
else
    VN="$DEFAULT_VERSION"
fi

VN=$(expr "$VN" : v*'\(.*\)')

# Show the version to the user via stderr
echo >&2 "version: $VN"

# Parse the existing VERSION-FILE 
if test -r $VF
then
    VC=$(sed -e 's/^version: //' <$VF)
else
    VC=unset
fi

# If version has changed, update VERSION-FILE
test "$VN" = "$VC" || {
    echo "version: $VN" >$VF
    echo >&2 "($VF updated)"
}
```

Comment: There are a couple of typos at the end of the script. Replace the last  3 lines with:

    VC=$(sed -e 's/^version: //' $VF)
    echo >&2 "($VF updated)"
fi


Note the closing ')' and replacing the last '}' with fi.

Comment: I think the renderer has swallowed several lines of the script.  I have submitted an edit to indent the code rather than wrapping it in code/pre tags.  The last few lines should be

`# Parse the existing VERSION-FILE `
`if test -r $VF`
`then`
` VC=$(sed -e 's/^version: //' <$VF)`
`else`
` VC=unset`
`fi`
`# If version has changed, update VERSION-FILE`
`test "$VN" = "$VC" || {`
` echo "version: $VN" >$VF`
` echo >&2 "($VF updated)"`
`}`

Comment: Wow, ugly.  I've put a copy of the entire script here: https://gist.github.com/880771

Comment: You may want to go to the original source, the official git.git repository: http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=blob;f=GIT-VERSION-GEN

Comment: Why not re-touching the version file even if the version has changed? Why wouldn't it be build-tool friendly?

Comment: `git describe --tags --long --abbrev=7`, result example: `v2.3.5-151-gf4c1dab`