# How can i get some sequential revision number in git

Tags: git, version-control

I am deploying the changes in `dev site` and some times the coders say that they have fixed the chnages in revision `pushed today`.

In mercurial i used to have at the botoom of the page the revision number like `r223` so that user will know that current revision is `r225`so its not the latest.

But in `git` i have only `hash` which is difficult to get if thats old revision than the mater now.

Is it possible to get some `sequential number` to be displayed on dev site so that i know how far dev site is behind

Comment: Check out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/677436/how-to-get-the-git-commit-count

Comment: As a side note, Mercurial's sequential version numbers can be misleading. Because it is a distributed system like Git, *your* revision 225 and *my* revision 225 are not guaranteed to be the same.

Comment: It might be better to use ``git describe`` so that a programmer can tell you "such and such a tag + 5 commits" when ``describe`` tells you the trunk is now at that tag + 11 commits.

Answer (score 0):

There is **no** way to do this in Git.

Git is distributed version control system, therefore any type of hooks or external counters can't guarantee sequential and uniqueness