# Use JGit to get the git commit count

Tags: jgit

With the git command-line, the way to [get the git commit count](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4061706/89218) is

```
git rev-list HEAD --count
```

How to do this with JGit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `LogCommand` to obtain the number of commits like so:

```java
Iterable<RevCommit> commits = git.log().call();
int count = 0;
for( RevCommit commit : commits ) {
  count++;
}
```

If not specified otherwise the command starts at HEAD. With `add()` multiple commit-ids can be added to start the graph traversal from or `all()` can be called to start from all known branches.

Answer (score 2):

More compact answer:

```
int countCommits = Iterables.size(git.log().call());
```

Comment: This has bad performance because it fetches all commits. My repo can have tens of thousands of commits such that getting all of them is too slow. Is there a JGit method that has better performance?