# git commit count without pulling the branch

Tags: git, jenkins

I have a very large git history and building this on Jenkins takes quite a bit
of time. There is a shallow clone option not to clone the entire tree, this makes
the build much faster.

But since we use the commit counts as an identifier of the build numbers, I cannot
use the shallow clone option.

I have looked at options here:
[How do I get the Git commit count?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677436/how-to-get-the-git-commit-count)

```
git rev-list --count <revision>
```

but this seems to require you clone the entire repo,

Is there perhaps a git command to get the commit count "remotely" without
cloning the entire repo?

Answer (score 0):

There is not a git command to do that, because there are not "remote" git commands. Git, by very nature, is a *distributed* system, meaning it operates on its own locally distributed copy of the data set.

You might be able to emulate what you want, by talking to a remote git installation, though, if you have shell access on the git server, via SSH:

```
ssh $githost git rev-list --count
```

Comment: ssh -c cipher_spec  is for the cipher spec.
I am wondering if Stash has some REST API to get the the count.

Comment: I have a clone path, such as ssh://git@hostname:port/directory/project.git
How can I use this url together with the ssh command?