# Error (27,0) for input string:"" in build.gradle file from plaid-master

Tags: android, git

```
// query git for the SHA, Tag and commit count. Use these to automate versioning.
25: def gitSha = 'git rev-parse --short HEAD'.execute([], project.rootDir).text.trim()
26: def gitTag = 'git describe --tags'.execute([], project.rootDir).text.trim()
27: def gitCommitCount = 100 +Integer.parseInt('git rev-list --count HEAD'.execute([], project.rootDir).text.trim())
```

after gradle:

Error:(27, 0) For input string: ""
\plaid-master\app\build.gradle

Answer (score 2):

1.click here [how to get git commit count?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677436/how-to-get-the-git-commit-count)

2.i think there is no **.git** folder in my project,and throw an error caused by Integer parseInt("")

3.just change

```
def gitCommitCount = 100 +Integer.parseInt('git rev-list --count HEAD'.execute([], project.rootDir).text.trim())
```

to

```
def gitCommitCount = 100 +Integer.parseInt('git rev-list --count HEAD'.execute([], project.rootDir).text.trim()+"0")
```

or `def gitCommitCount =100`