# Getting Sum of Commits on Two Branches

Tags: git, zsh

So I have a build shell script that calculates a build number for a mobile application based on the count of commits to the HEAD branch (BUILD_NUMBER=`git rev-list HEAD --count`)

Is there a way of getting the total number of commits across two branches? Either in a single git command or in multiple lines in the script? Not well versed in either git or zsh :(

To be clear, what I am seeking is a way to get the SUM of commits in two branches (count of commits in branch1 + count of commits in branch2) Can this be done in a single command? Is there a way to do it in multiple steps within the build shell script?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+count+commits

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4061706/7976758 : `git rev-list --all --count`

Comment: this give me the count of commits across ALL branch...what about only two branches? @phd

Comment: `git rev-list --count branch1 branch2`

Comment: @phd I think that's sufficiently valuable to make its own Answer and may be just what they're after

Comment: @phd thanks for the reply. I’ve tried that command with the two branch but it gives a different result. I don’t think that is the SUM of both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `HEAD`, just give the branch name

However, it's possible the number will be the same for many branches with different commits, say

```
main:     aaaaaaa -> bbbbbbb
feature1: aaaaaaa -> bbbbbbb -> ccccccc
feature2: aaaaaaa -> bbbbbbb -> ddddddd
```

Also note you may want to `git pull` and use `origin/branchname` to avoid having to update the local copy of each branch individually

---

You can add numbers in most modern shells with [`$(())` syntax](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/dblparens.html)

```bash
% echo "$((10 + 11))"
21
```

All together

```bash
% echo "$(( $(git rev-list --count origin/feature1) + $(git rev-list --count origin/feature2) ))"
500
```

However, assuming the final result is the combination of two branches, it would be best to try and merge to ensure you get the true commit count, perhaps in a temporary branch

Comment: is there a way to sum the count of commits on two separate but similarly named branches?

Comment: sure - you could just use like `$(())` - let me add a little

Comment: thank you so much. I dont much experience with the syntax and had tried a bunch of different things so this was exactly what I needed. this needs to be done for a stupid reason based on our client's pipeline but I agree the merge would be the best strategy.